# Undefined value is picked from select tag in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

This how I am trying to display values in form for a field:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label >Doctor Name</label>
    <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="">Select Role</option>
        @{
            foreach (var d in ViewBag.Doc)
            {

                <option value="d.DoctorId">@d.FirstName</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

I am trying pick to doctor's id and store it patients db where it'll be a foreign key. However, value of Doctor's ID which gets picked up is always "0".

If I inspect the element, the value on the form is correct.

[image]

I am not getting why it does pick zero then.

Comment: You may need to give it a 'name' attribute, with the same value as the property you are expecting it to bind to in your controller. I.e. <select name="DoctorId" ...

Comment: How are you Binding that select? Because currentl;y there's no name attribute for it. Add name attribute with the property name that you defined on your Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set name for Select

```
<select name="YOUR_MODEL_ATTR_NAME" class="custom-select">
```